# In R, how to modify/ re-assign a list element using index?

Tags: r, list, indexing, variable-assignment

## Question:

How do I modify an element within an established list and re-assign it back to the list in the same index/position?

## Setup and Example

First, here's a dataframe that I am breaking up by groups into a list:

```
library(tidyverse) # Not absolutely required, but I'm working this way.
df <- tibble(A = rep(paste("Group", c(1:3)),3), 
             B = seq(1, 18, 2),
             C = (1:9))
lst <- df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  group_split()
```

Dataframe and resulting list should be as below:

```
> df
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  A           B     C
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Group 1     1     1
2 Group 2     3     2
3 Group 3     5     3
4 Group 1     7     4
5 Group 2     9     5
6 Group 3    11     6
7 Group 1    13     7
8 Group 2    15     8
9 Group 3    17     9

> lst
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    A: character
    B: double
    C: integer
  >
>[3]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  A           B     C
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Group 1     1     1
2 Group 1     7     4
3 Group 1    13     7

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  A           B     C
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Group 2     3     2
2 Group 2     9     5
3 Group 2    15     8

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  A           B     C
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Group 3     5     3
2 Group 3    11     6
3 Group 3    17     9
```

### Here's the problem...

For reasons irrelevant here, I need to give each sub-dataframe in the list a different treatment based on the Group.  I thought I could apply the modifications in a loop like below, leaving the list structure in place.

```
for (j in 1:3){
  lst[[j]] <- lst[[j]] %>% 
    mutate(D = B * C)
}
```

...but that throws this error:

```
Error in `[[<-`:
! Can't convert from `value` <tbl_df<
  A: character
  B: double
  C: integer
  D: double
>> to <tbl_df<
  A: character
  B: double
  C: integer
>> due to loss of precision.
```

I know that the assignment back to the list is the problem, because I can successfully do this:

```
df2 <- NULL
df_final <- NULL

for (j in 1:3){
  
  df2 <- lst[[j]] %>% 
    mutate(D = B * C)
  
  df_final <- rbind(df_final, df2)
}
df_final
```

...which returns a dataframe that I could break back up as in the beginning.

```
> df_final
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  A           B     C     D
  <chr>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 Group 1     1     1     1
2 Group 1     7     4    28
3 Group 1    13     7    91
4 Group 2     3     2     6
5 Group 2     9     5    45
6 Group 2    15     8   120
7 Group 3     5     3    15
8 Group 3    11     6    66
9 Group 3    17     9   153
```

...but I feel like I'm missing some nuance in how the list could be assigned "in place" as above, and I don't understand the error message.  What am I missing about assigning to lists that makes `lst[[j]] <- lst[[j]] %>% <ANY MODIFICATION>` fail?

Comment: I don't know much about the `vctrs` package, but the problem seems to be that `group_split` **doesn't** return a usual list. It's class is `"vctrs_list_of" "vctrs_vctr"    "list"`, and apparently these classes's methods don't like your code. If you convert it to a regular old list `lst <- as.list(lst)`, then your code will work just fine.

Comment: `bind_cols(df)%>%mutate(D = B * C)%>%group_split(A)`??

Comment: If you use the boring old `split` like `df %>% split(.$A)` you can use your loop just fine.

Comment: @GregorThomas Okay, thank you.  I didn't realize that I wasn't getting a normal list that I was reading about.  I understand now why examples I looked at weren't helping me.  I see an answer below that says as much, so I'll accept that, but thank you for the comment.

Comment: @thelatemail I appreciate that suggestion, as I'm perhaps too reliant on `tidyverse`.  I could use your base suggestion and save text.

Comment: Checking again, I note that `group_split()` is listed in R help as "lifecycle : experimental" as of dplyr v1.0.9, so perhaps this is a reason to avoid its use, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `group_split()` is not a simple list, but has some track to the tables inside it that prevents modification of only one item.
You can avoid this with `lst <- as.list(lst)`.

```
library(dplyr) # Not absolutely required, but I'm working this way.

df <- tibble(A = rep(paste("Group", c(1:3)),3), 
             B = seq(1, 18, 2),
             C = (1:9))
lst <- df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  group_split()

for (j in 1:3){
  lst[[j]] <- lst[[j]] %>% 
    mutate(D = B * C)
}
#> Error in `[[<-`:
#> ! Can't convert from `value` <tbl_df<
#>   A: character
#>   B: double
#>   C: integer
#>   D: double
#> >> to <tbl_df<
#>   A: character
#>   B: double
#>   C: integer
#> >> due to loss of precision.

lst <- as.list(lst)

for (j in 1:3){
  lst[[j]] <- lst[[j]] %>% 
    mutate(D = B * C)
} # OK

df_final <- bind_rows(lst)

df_final
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   A           B     C     D
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Group 1     1     1     1
#> 2 Group 1     7     4    28
#> 3 Group 1    13     7    91
#> 4 Group 2     3     2     6
#> 5 Group 2     9     5    45
#> 6 Group 2    15     8   120
#> 7 Group 3     5     3    15
#> 8 Group 3    11     6    66
#> 9 Group 3    17     9   153
```

***OR***

you can use `map` to map the function to every item of the list.

```
lst <- map(lst, ~ mutate(., D=B*C))
df_final <- bind_rows(lst)
df_final
```

Comment: Pointing out that the list isn't a regular list is the part I was missing.  This gets me home.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential solution using `purrr`:

```r
library(tidyverse) # Not absolutely required, but I'm working this way.
df <- tibble(A = rep(paste("Group", c(1:3)),3), 
             B = seq(1, 18, 2),
             C = (1:9))
df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_df(~.x %>% mutate(D = B * C))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   A           B     C     D
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Group 1     1     1     1
#> 2 Group 1     7     4    28
#> 3 Group 1    13     7    91
#> 4 Group 2     3     2     6
#> 5 Group 2     9     5    45
#> 6 Group 2    15     8   120
#> 7 Group 3     5     3    15
#> 8 Group 3    11     6    66
#> 9 Group 3    17     9   153

# conditionally mutate based on group
# could also just do this with a dataframe though
df %>% 
  split(.$A) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    x %>% 
      mutate(D = case_when(A == "Group 1" ~ B + C,
                           A == "Group 2" ~ B + 1000,
                           A == "Group 3" ~ B * C))
  })
#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   A           B     C     D
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 Group 1     1     1     2
#> 2 Group 1     7     4    11
#> 3 Group 1    13     7    20
#> 4 Group 2     3     2  1003
#> 5 Group 2     9     5  1009
#> 6 Group 2    15     8  1015
#> 7 Group 3     5     3    15
#> 8 Group 3    11     6    66
#> 9 Group 3    17     9   153
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate the alternate suggestion with `purrr`, which gives me something to think about, but my goal was to focus on understanding why the assignment I was attempting didn't work.  My example is simplified, and for my purposes, the loop structure I think needs to stay due to some complexity I didn't show (or I need to get better to understand how to best use your suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Using R base functions also works

```
tmp <- lapply(lst, function(x){
  do.call(cbind, list(x, D=(x$B*x$C)))
})

do.call(rbind, tmp)
```

Result:

```
       A  B C   D
1 Group 1  1 1   1
2 Group 1  7 4  28
3 Group 1 13 7  91
4 Group 2  3 2   6
5 Group 2  9 5  45
6 Group 2 15 8 120
7 Group 3  5 3  15
8 Group 3 11 6  66
9 Group 3 17 9 153
```